# Disable edition in a TextBox with Scrolling enabled

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i would like to know if it is possible to disable the edition of a textbox without losing the scrolling capability. If the Enabled property is set to false then the scroll bars are also disabled

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Disable text selection:

```
 ContextMenu blankContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
 textBox1.ContextMenu = blankContextMenu;
```

For disabling Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, capture them on KeyDown event

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the readonly property.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to disable text selection?

Comment: I have not touched windows forms in several years so unfortunately no, but it is possible that there is a "Selectable" property. Perhaps someone more "up-to-date" can answer this part.

Answer (score 0):

Is easy to do that you just must to

```
// set readonly property true
ReadOnly = True;

// set cursor property to default
Cursor = Default;

// change focus when it has on enter event
private void textBox4_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label8.Focus();
}
```